# Unix shell - Best way to replace all occurrence of whitespace in string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a string like

```
'abc', '<<some string with space>>', 'xyz'
```

I want to get a string like below:-

```
'abc', '<<some_string_with_space>>', 'xyz'
```

Comment: A newline is a space - can your quoted string include newlines? Can it include escaped quotes (`\'` or `''`)? Can it contain commas? Can you have an empty field `''`? Does the target string **really** always start with `<<` and end with `>>`? Put some effort into coming up with concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers all of your use cases so we're not guessing at your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply with **`awk`**:

```
s="'abc', '<<some string with space>>', 'xyz'"
awk -F', ' '{ gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"_",$2) }1' OFS=', ' <<<"$s"
```

The output:

```
'abc', '<<some_string_with_space>>', 'xyz'
```

Comment: How about `s="'hello, world'"`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, it doesn't work when string doesn't have whitespace between ','. s="'abc','<<some string with space>>','xyz'"

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, how about elaborating all possible inputs? We have a concrete case

Comment: @AbhashUpadhyaya, you should have mentioned that in your question. Be more exact

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I was able to do it with some tweaking. I would have mentioned all scenarios had I know all well in advance. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed too

```
echo "'abc', '<<some string with space>>', 'xyz'" | sed s'/ /_/g;s/,_/, /g'
```

Comment: How about `echo "'hello, world'" | sed s'/ /_/g;s/,_/, /g'`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, yes you are right, if it's always in << ... >>, we can use sed -E ':A;s/(<[^ ]*)( )([^,]*,)/\1_\3/;tA'

Answer (score 0):

If your question concerns the generalized problem of replacing spaces with `_` **only inside single-quoted strings `'...'` but not in other parts**,
I would solve that using Perl, following this logic:

- For each `'...'` in the input (using regex: `'[^']+'`)
- Execute a function that replaces all spaces with `_`

Like this:

```
echo "'abc', '<<some string with space>>', 'xyz'" |\
  perl -pe 'sub r { $_ = @_[0]; s/ +/_/g; return $_; }; s/'"'[^']+'"'/r($&)/ge'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ":a;s/^\(\('[^']*',\s*\)*'[^' ]*\) /\1_/;ta" file
```

or perhaps more securely:

```
sed ':a;s/^\(\('\''[^'\'']*'\'',\s*\)*'\''[^'\'' ]*\) /\1_/;ta' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Use awk's gsub with regular expression \s to replace whitespace characters.

```
mystr = "my sentence is this!"
gsub(/\s/,"_",mystr)
print mystr
```

Comment: I didin't downvote but you should mention that's GNU awk only for `\s` - with other awks you'd need `[[:space:]]`.